# Link component not working with Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

The style not working

```
const MenuOption = styled(Link)`
  font-size: 14px;
`;
```

Only using pseudo-class that styles its works

Comment: Can you provide more detail/context about what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to Make a styled `div` or `ul` and then wrap it around `link` tag. Maybe make a component for it.

Example:

```
const NavBarLinkDiv = styled.div`
  //your styles
`;

export default const NavBarLink = ({ children, to }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={to}>
      <NavBarLinkDiv>{children} </NavBarLinkDiv>
    </Link>
  );
};
```